# keeping the UI component's state on the server side

Tags: jsf, view

I have been reading about saving the view state of components in JSF. I dont know if I have got it. Some questions:

1) The component view state are the validators, converters and some other stuff attached to the form fields and the reason they are saved is because you can change them programmatically; for example with the next code: ...."getComponent().setRendered(false)" I could change the visibility of a component and this would be saved in the state of the component,  right?

2) These components view states are saved in session , right? Because I could want to hide some component for a user and  make the same component visible to another user, right?

3)The values of input forms, are saved in the state of UIComponents? I mean in the components itself and not in backed beans. If yes, why?

4) Are there other stuff besides converters, validators of a form that is saved in the state of the component?

5) Is possible to change validators, converters, add/delete form fields, modify a cssClass of a component,etc... programmatically?